# How to get Total Result count using searchAfter approach

Tags: lucene, pagination

In my current implementation of Lucene 4.3 where there are millions of indexed records, I do a regular search() and get the topDocs.totalHits as the count of results.

As part of this, I store all the results in the session and then let the user paginate through the results. With this, I am able to show the "First" "Previous" "Next" and "Last" links for navigation along with the "Page 1 of 500" display.

Obviously, this led to memory issues and I have now decided to use the searchAfter() method and hence avoid storing the huge result set in memory.

Question 1: How can I get the total result count in this case? Is it even possible as I won't be getting the entire resultset?

Question 2: I know I can provide the "Previous" and "Next" options for paginating, but is there anyway I can still provide the "Last" page option, as to do that I would need to provide the document object just before the last page begins.

Please suggest.

Regards,
Raghu

Answer (score 0):

1 - It will still be in `totalHits`.  As it sounds like, it tells you the total number of hits, even if that number is greater than the number of hits you've requested.

2 - It does beg the question, somewhat, of why you would want to jump to the last page, ie. the *worst* results.  Regardless though, the best way to do this would be to use a [search call the accepts a `Collector`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#search%28org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Filter,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Collector%29).  Passing in a [`TopScoreDocCollector`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/TopScoreDocCollector.html), for instance, would allow you to get the last page something like:

```java
int pageSize = 10;
TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(maxHits, true);
searcher.search(query, collector);
collector.topDocs(collector.getTotalHits() - pageSize);
```